# Resharper: Is there a way to enable auto-completion for resource IDs in XAML with WPF Localization Extension?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, resharper

On a C# project I'm using the [WPF Localization Extension](https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension) for localization.

In XAML files it looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{lex:Loc MyResourceId}" />
```

Is there a way to set up Reshaper to have auto-completion when I type resource IDs like "MyResourceId"?

Comment: That usually works in the visual studio without the ReSharper. I have VS2013 and ReSharper 8.x and it works fine for me. What might be the cause of this feature not working is because of complex visual tree structure of your Container? Which has happened to me -_- HTH.

Comment: Really? Just tried with a very basic XAML file, didn't work. I'm using VS2013 and Resharper8.x too...

Comment: And how would VS know how to auto-complete? The key is basically just an arbitrary string, the lookup happens on runtime. I was thinking about writing an Resharper extension to do that, but I'm note sure how complicate that is

Comment: I am not lying if that's what you're asking ;-). I wrote the comment because I did get the info about `StaticResource` when I was using it in a `Style`. Dunno why but it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't. Wasn't really issue if you ask me, I just coped with it. BTW the resources that I was using were defined in the same `xaml` dile and not in a `ResourceDctionary`, think that might affect it quite a bit.

Comment: Ah, I see. No, you are not lying, it's just a different scenario ;-)
In the example code in the question MyResourceId is NOT referring to a StaticResource, but to a (non WPF) plain string resource. MyResourcedId is the ID for it, it is matched to a (localized) string on runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  ReSharper's smart completion doesn't have any way of inferring valid resource keys by analyzing the markup extension.  It doesn't even know that `Key` represents a resource key, nor does it know how the WPF Localization Extension parses keys and maps them to the underlying localization provider.  All it knows is that `LocExtension` expects a `string` value; it doesn't know what that value represents.

Looking at the localization APIs, it does not appear that `ILocalizationProvider` even provides a way of querying which keys are available; you can only give it a key, and it will try to give you a value back.  Unfortunately, that rules out the possibility of implementing completion support yourself in the form of a ReSharper extension.  You'd need to modify the localization library too.

Comment: Well, changing the localization library wouldn't be a big deal I guess. Is there a way to do that so Resharper would use that query interface for auto-completion? Or would I need to change the library AND write a Resharper extension?

Comment: I can't think of any way for ReSharper to "just work" in this scenario, so someone would need to write a ReSharper extension in addition to changing the localization library.